# SQL select & count from two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, "users" & "projects"

users table:

id username

---

1 sam

2 peter

3 andy

projects table:

id title uid

---

1 pr1 0

2 pr2 1

3 pr3 2

4 pr4 1

projects.uid represents the user id who will do the job and 0 means this project is not assigned to any user yet.

I want a query to count and group projects based on users & return something like this:

uid project_count

---

0 1

1 2

2 1

3 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks so much for your answers but none of them seems to return right rows,

here is my newly found answer:

```
SELECT users.id,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM projects WHERE projects.user_id = users.id) as 'count' FROM users ORDER BY id
```

I'm not pretty sure about it's performance but currently it works...

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not returning `username`, you only need the `projects` table:

```
select u.id, count(*) as project_count
from users u
left outer join projects p on u.id = p.uid 
group by u.id
order by u.id
```

If you want the username too, you can do this:

```
select u.id, u.username, count(*) as project_count
from users u
left outer join projects p on u.id = p.uid
group by u.id, u.username
order by u.id
```

Comment: A very very minor point... I think only the second version would have the desired output regardless of whether username was required because of this row in the OPs desired output `3 0` so the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to projects is required.

Comment: @GarethD good point, didn't notice that, I have update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.id, count(p.uid)
from users u
inner join project p 
on u.id = p.uid
group by p.uid
```